# Placing a component on the face of Another component in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, interface, label, jlabel

I'm Facing a problem while I try to add a label on the face of just another label in Java Netbeans. Every time I add a label just above of another label the new label (say label2) automatically goes to the leftmost side and shrink my first label( say label1). Actually, I want to add a background color blue to the top of the form as there are no other possible ways (as I know) to change certain parts of the form to another color I use this way. If there is another way of changing the background of certain parts of a form, share with me. But also help to add a label just above another label.

Thanks in advance .. :)

The following Image will show you my intention. Notice only to the head. There is a label on the left side of a blue label. I want to add that label on the surface of the blue label.

[image]

[This is the image of Interface which I want to gain in JAVA. This is a Visual Basic MDI Form and list of options are available on the rightmost side. That's what I try to do but couldn't do yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSDld.jpg)

Comment: Are you using a JSplitPane with JPanels in each Pane?

Comment: Nope. I'm using free Design  Layout. The black in color is the Desktop pane. Both blues in color is the Label with a border 200 to fill with blue color. And both labels have own Panel as a background.

Comment: Actually, I want to do something like this structure which I developed using Visual Basic but I want to change following in JAVA. The URL of image is following 


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aAZVp8i2yRZsC0gyr5RBVUHUTlmm8bAJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This can be easily done by using three JPanels. Then, place your desired JLabel(s), JButton(s), etc within whichever JPanel(s) you like. Change the border for each of the three JPanels to **Etched-Raised**.

Comment: It's not working yet by the method you told me. But I got another method of completing my job. But Thanks for your co-operation.  #DevilsHnd